# How to prevent margin to overflow in CSS?

Tags: html, css, bootstrap-4

In the following code I notice the last row overflow the parent container. I have tried to use `overflow: auto;` but this adds scrollbars. How can I avoid the overflow?

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/4.1.2/css/bootstrap.min.css">

<style>
    #a { height: 33%}
    #b { height: 17%}
    #c { height: 50%}
</style>
<div class="container border border-warning" style="height: 400px">
  <div id="a" class="row bg-primary m-2">A</div>
  <div id="b" class="row bg-secondary m-2">B</div>
  <div id="c" class="row bg-info m-2">C</div>
 </div>
```

https://codepen.io/anon/pen/PBLyZB

Comment: have your tried `.container{  overflow: hidden; }` ?

Comment: `overflow: hidden` on the parent `.container` will do the trick, or better still; make sure that the sum of  `height + margin` for each row is not bigger then 100%... eg; `height: calc(33% - 16px)`

Comment: to add on what @giorgio said... for you it would be something like this: `#a { height: calc(33% - 1rem) }` because the `.m-2` class gives the element .5 rem on top and .5 rem on bottom so you need to remove 1rem total.

Comment: @zgood no, it's not good due to margin collapsing, because between each element we only have 0.5rem so the total margin in the cotainer is 2rem and not 3rem

Comment: @TemaniAfif opps I see... you are correct. It would have to be something like this `#a { height: calc(33% - 1rem)} #b { height: 17%} #c { height: calc(50% - 1rem)}` which just seems awkward, and not flex-able.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Simply make the container a flex container and you will have the shrink effect that will fix the issue. Then adjust the margin of the middle one to keep the same spacing like when you had margin-collapsing *(flexbox disable margin-collapsing)*.

```css
#a { height: 33%}
#b { height: 17%}
#c { height: 50%}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/4.1.2/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<div class="container border border-warning d-flex flex-column" style="height: 400px">
  <div id="a" class="row bg-primary m-2">A</div>
  <div id="b" class="row bg-secondary mx-2">B</div><!-- margin only on the left and right -->
  <div id="c" class="row bg-info m-2">C</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use `display:flex`. add `display: flex; flex-direction: column;` to the parent style.

Or you can use `calc` to reduce the `margin` from the `height` -

```
#a { height: calc(33% - 0.5rem) }
#b { height: calc(17% - 0.5rem) }
#c { height: calc(50% - 0.5rem) }
```

Comment: the calc is a bit tricky here due to margin collapsing, actually you are missing one margin ... initially they are 6, and 4 are collpasing so you have at the end 4 margins and you need to remove all of them or the last element will be close to the edge

Answer (score 0):

Add the overflow property on the parent element.

```
  .container {
        overflow: hidden;
    }
```

Check documentation on : [CSS overflow property](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/overflow)

Answer (score 0):

It is because there is a margin on A,B,C (because of m-2), and the full height of the 3 divs is 100% + 4*8px, more than the height of the container.

So you have to change the height of the container for `auto` if its not important to be 400px. (It would be 432 px.)

Or

You have to remove m-2 and change the `margin` to `padding: .5rem` and add `box-sizing: border-box` to A,B,C if the padding between the divs and the height ratio is important.

Or

Add `overflow: hidden` to the container, so the last divs overflow wont be visible, but in that case the `#c { height: 50%}` wouldn't be true.

Comment: Both your first and last solution ain't really working solutions as they don't give the desired outcome. However the second solution could work. Although i would just use the `p-2` class with a `box-sizing: border-box;` solution, insted of rewriting css. This however would make them "touch" each other.

Answer (score 0):

```css
#a { height: 33%}
#b { height: 17%}
#c { height: 50%}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/4.1.2/css/bootstrap.min.css">

<div class="container d-flex flex-column p-2 border border-warning " style="height: 400px;">
  <div id="a" class="row bg-primary mx-2">A</div>
  <div id="b" class="row bg-secondary m-2">B</div>
  <div id="c" class="row bg-info mx-2">C</div>
</div>
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers in the [help center](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score -1):

The div boxes do not fit into the parent div box because of the margin space below each child div. The margin space below the divs is 8px. Total space occupied by margin is 32px which is 8% of the total space. So you must reduce the percentage height of each child div by 8/3px which is around 2px from each and 1px from any 2 of the divs.